# How to set cookie path in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am trying to set cookie path so that they should not be accessible to other applications on a shared server if path is set to root i.e. "/"

I am trying to set it as follows in web.config file:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/account/logon" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" path="my_virtual_directory_name" />
```

I know this will only work for ".ASPXAUTH" cookie. In my case path is set to this cookie and another cookie with same name is created with path set as root.

I need to set path for all cookies and there should not be duplication of cookies, one with proper path and another with path set to root.

Please suggest me how can I set a fixed path for all cookies in asp.net mvc 4 application.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very basic example showing how to set the cookie path.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
             new HttpCookie("test", "hello") { Path = @"/admin", 
             Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)});

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks matt..Your approach will work best when we are adding user defined cookies.. But there are certain cookies which are automatically added by MVC such as: 1) ASP.NET_SessionId
2) __RequestVerificationToken_L0lMLU1BUw2
3) .ASPXAUTH   .. etc. Approach suggested by you will not work for these cookies... What I want is to add path to all cookies including auto-generated and custom added (ex..test cookie which you defined.)

Answer (score 0):

use this is asp.net C#

```
 HttpCookie cookies=  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["sessionstarttime"];
            cookies.Value = "Value of Cookies";
            cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
            cookies.Path = "/";
```

if you are using JQuery then use following

```
$.cookie("sessionstarttime", "Value",{ path: '/' });
```